# How to implement different click events for child of expandable list?

Tags: android, click, expandablelistview

In my expandable list view I have a `textView` and an `imagebutton`. When I click on the `textView` or child view of expandable list, it should show an `alertbox`. I can achieve this by using `onChildClick` but I have an `imagebutton` inside the child view after `textView`. When I click on this, it should perform another activity. I don't know how to implement this in an expandable list.

Here is my expandable list code. Please check it. I tried `android:onClick="myClickHandler"` too. I'm getting some `illegalstateException`.

Here is my code:

```
import android.app.ExpandableListActivity;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ExpandableListView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.SimpleExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import android.util.Log;

public class CoctailsActivity extends ExpandableListActivity implements OnClickListener
{
    private static final String LOG_TAG = "ElistCBox";
    public static ImageButton img_button;

    static final String Group[] = {
      "A",
      "B",
      "C",
      "D"
    };

    static final String Children[][] = {
      {
        "lightgrey",
        "dimgray",
        "sgi gray 92"
      },
      {
        "dodgerblue 2",
        "steelblue 2",
        "powderblue",
      },
      {
        "yellow 1",
        "gold 1",
        "darkgoldenrod 1",
      },
      {
        "indianred 1",
        "firebrick 1",
        "maroon",
      }
    };

    /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle icicle)
    {
        super.onCreate(icicle);
        setContentView(R.layout.exp_list);

        SimpleExpandableListAdapter expListAdapter =new SimpleExpandableListAdapter
            (
                this,
                createGroupList(),  
                R.layout.group_row, 
                new String[] { "Group" },   
                new int[] { R.id.group_name },      
                createChildList(),  
                R.layout.child_row, 
                new String[] { "Children"}, 
                new int[] { R.id.child_name }   
            );
        setListAdapter( expListAdapter );


    }

    public void  onContentChanged  () 
    {
        super.onContentChanged();
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onContentChanged" );
    }
    public void myClickHandler(View v) 
    {
        Log.v( LOG_TAG, "insideMyHandler" );



        ExpandableListView lvItems = getExpandableListView();
        for (int i=0; i < lvItems.getChildCount(); i++) 
        {
            lvItems.getChildAt(i).setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);        
        }



        LinearLayout vwParentRow = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();

        TextView child = (TextView)vwParentRow.getChildAt(0);
        Button btnChild = (Button)vwParentRow.getChildAt(1);
        btnChild.setText(child.getText());
        btnChild.setText("I've been clicked!");

        int c = Color.CYAN;

        vwParentRow.setBackgroundColor(c); 
        vwParentRow.refreshDrawableState();       
    }


   public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent,View v,int groupPosition,int childPosition,long id) 
   {
        Log.d( LOG_TAG, "onChildClick: "+childPosition );

        return false;
    }

    public void  onGroupExpand  (int groupPosition) {
        Log.d( LOG_TAG,"onGroupExpand: "+groupPosition );
    }

    private List<HashMap<String, String>> createGroupList() {
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> result = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
      for( int i = 0 ; i < Group.length ; ++i ) {
        HashMap<String, String> m = new HashMap<String, String>();
        m.put( "Group",Group[i] );
        result.add( m );
      }
      return (List<HashMap<String, String>>)result;
    }

  private List<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> createChildList() {
    ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>> result = new ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>>();
    for( int i = 0 ; i < Children.length ; ++i ) 
    {
// Second-level lists
      ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> secList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>();
      for( int n = 0 ; n < Children[i].length ; n += 2 ) 
      {
        HashMap<String, String> child = new HashMap<String, String>();
        child.put( "Children", Children[i][n] );
        //child.put( "rgb", shades[i][n+1] );
        secList.add( child );
      }
      result.add( secList );
    }
    return result;
  }

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    img_button =(ImageButton)v.findViewById(R.id.img01);
    if(img_button!=null){
        Log.v( LOG_TAG, "onclick clickedddddd" );
    }

}

}
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried this myself, but I'm thinking that the button's on click event can be handled by the activity, like you would any other button onClick event.

Possible have a read through on this article: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/ui-events.html

See if that helps.

Else, I'm sure you can just build an onClick listener object and pass it through the specific button. The link should help you out.

Comment: Thanx for the reply .i tried all those things.in my code i am using onChildClick event , wen ever i click on imagebutton onchildclick event only invoking ..why is it so.

Comment: It's difficult to say exactly without the source code. If possible post your source code for the activity. Like I said, I haven't tried it myself yet, but I imagine that all button clicks can be intercepted by doing the following

Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.yourimgbutton);
button.setOnClickListener(this);

And then handling it in the activity method OnClick

I think the onChildClick event is only if the user clicks on the entire row and triggers the event in the custom adapter, not the activity's onClickEvent. 

Hope that helps.

Comment: Maybe this can help too:

http://androidforbeginners.blogspot.com/2010/03/clicking-buttons-in-listview-row.html

Comment: here is my expandable list code .. pls check it , i tried that `android:onClick="myClickHandler"` dat too ...getting some illegalstateException hete is my code

Answer (score 0):

Kris , why not implement a `ExpandableListAdapte`r . They are in API demo sample -[ExpandableList1.java](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/ExpandableList1.html) and then override `getGroupView` or `getChildView` to set `onClickListeners` as you want .